# Create a sequence that starts from 1 when a column value changes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a certain column, table$NAME, consisted of several thousand rows, and looks like this:

```
   NAME    
1  namea
2  nameb
3  nameb
4  nameb
5  namec
6  named
7  named
8  named
9  namee
10 namee
.
.
.
```

What I want is to add a sequence in table$Counter that starts from 1 every time that `NAME` changes. The output should be something like:

```
   NAME   Counter
1  namea      1
2  nameb      1
3  nameb      2
4  nameb      3
5  namec      1
6  named      1
7  named      2
8  named      3
9  namee      1
10 namee      2
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option in `base R` is to get the `table` of 'Name' and wrap it with `sequence` (assuming that the 'Name' column is already ordered)

```
df1$Counter <- sequence(table(df1$Name))
```

---

Or with `ave`

```
with(df1, ave(seq_along(Name), Name, FUN = seq_along))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Name) %>%
   mutate(Counter = row_number())
```